# upload apk 0 supported devices

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to publish to Production a version of my app to the Play Store, but I am getting 0 supported devices and it is frustrating as I don't see why.
The app works fine on the android phones i have tested but i deployed via android studio and manually via copying the apk to the phone.
I have signed the APK too just in case anyone asks.
Google Play Store not reporting anything itself and I can click the link 'View in Store' and it is there but doesn't work as it think there are no supported devices.
I have seen similar questions on here with different API's so i have tried adjusting according to those tips with no luck still so i have raised my own question.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.chubb.carecall">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="com.chubb.carecall.CareCallApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name="com.chubb.carecall.CareCallService" />

        <service
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.bleviawifi.CommCareBeaconService"

             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.chubb.carecall.bleviawifi.CommCareBeaconService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- Jaalee service responsible for scanning beacons. -->
        <service
            android:name="com.jaalee.sdk.service.BeaconService"
            android:exported="false"
             >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.chubb.carecall.bleviawifi.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="com.chubb.carecall.CareCallService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--<receiver
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.receivers.BootUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DummyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SlidingToolbarActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/care_call_alarms"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.AlarmActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm"
            android:parentActivityName="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/PreferenceTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MessageListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_messages"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/ActivityDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MessageListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.chubb.carecall.activities.MessageListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.BreakActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_break"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TransparentTheme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.ContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.CallActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_call"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.RecoverHolderActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recover_holder"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/ActivityDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:name="com.chubb.carecall.activities.LicensesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chubb.communitycare.carecall"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.1.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.github.shell-software', name: 'fab', version: '1.1.2'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Nick

Comment: Have you tried to appear your application in playstore from your device? @NickFurness

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" />
```

to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Lowercase "c"

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

> Descriptor string values are case-sensitive.